# picking contents out of lists python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
deck = [[6, "club"], [8, "diamond"], [3, "spade"]]

print(deck[1])
```

This prints:

```
[8, "diamond"]
```

Straightforward enough, but is there anyway to just print '8'.
Just print the first part of deck[1].
I tried:

```
print(deck[1[0]])
```

but that did not work. It was only a guess. Any ideas.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: `deck` is an array of arrays. Using `deck[1]` you get the second element of `deck`. To get the first element of *that* array, add another `[0]` to get `deck[1][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax is `deck[1][0]`.

Demo:

```
>>> deck = [[6, "club"], [8, "diamond"], [3, "spade"]]
>>> deck[1][0]
8
```

Comment: Haha how did I not think of that. Thanks for the answer!!